# Why won't the sprites move upward?

Tags: python, image, pygame, blit

I made a class for my game:

```
class Magazine(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, shooter):
        self.image = image
        self.xCoord = shooter.xCoord + (shooter.image.get_width()/2) - (self.image.get_width()/2)
        self.yCoord = shooter.yCoord - self.image.get_height()

    def update(self):
        self.yCoord -= 5
        if self.yCoord <= 0 - self.image.get_height():
            self.kill()
```

I created an item of this class, blitting it using the xCoord and the yCoord in the game loop:

```
    for gameObject in gameObjects:
        gameObject.update()
gameObjectsBlittingCounter = 0

for gameObject in gameObjects:
    screen.blit(gameObjects[gameObjectBlittingCounter].image,       ((gameObjects[gameObjectBlittingCounter].xCoord),         (gameObjects[gameObjectBlittingCounter].yCoord)))
    gameObjectBlittingCounter += 1
```

The item is in the gameObjects list. However, it only blits the object in the same spot over and over, without moving. Why?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the code where you're blitting, but if you are using the image's own `rect` via like `MySprite.image.get_rect()` or whatever, its x and y coordinates need to be updated (or set) as well. Just moving the obj.xCoord and obj.yCoord won't automatically update the rect; one thing you can do in such a situation is to pass an argument for the rect's position as you're calling `get_rect()`. For example:

```
target_rect = MySprite.image.get_rect(topleft=(MySprite.xCoord, MySprite.yCoord))
MyScreen.blit(MySprite.image, target_rect)
```

The above code would need to be called each time the image is drawn.

Another option is to have the sprite's `rect` attribute updated in tandem with the yCoord. There are a couple of ways to do this. You can do it explicitly:

```
def update(self):
    self.y -= 5
    self.rect.y -= 5
```

You can also use properties to make sure that your object is always referencing and updating the rect's x and y coordinates, but that turns into quite a bit more code.

```
class MySprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, x, y):
        super(MySprite, self).__init__()
        self.image = image
        self.rect = image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))
        self._x = x
        self._y = y

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, v):
        self._x = v
        self.rect.x = self._x

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, v):
        self._y = v
        self.rect.y = self._y
```

In this way, `MySprite.x` is always the x of the rect object, as is `MySprite.y`.

Regardless, whatever coordinates are being used to draw the sprite need to be updated along with the sprite's independent x and y coordinates.

Comment: Where I blit, here is the code that should work:

for gameObject in gameObjects:

Comment: for gameObject in gameObjects:
                    screen.blit(gameObjects[gameObjectBlittingCounter].image,         ((gameObjects[gameObjectBlittingCounter].xCoord),         (gameObjects[gameObjectBlittingCounter].yCoord)))
            gameObjectBlittingCounter += 1

Proper format of course

Answer (score 0):

Check your self.yCoord is >= 0, there's a chance it won't be therefore resulting in no movement.

Also, can't you replace

```
gameObjectBlittingCounter = 0
for gameObject in gameObjects:
    gameObjects[gameObjectBlittingCounter].update()
    gameObjectBlittingCounter += 1
```

with:

```
for gameObject in gameObjects:
    gameObject.update()
```

Comment: Hmm good points but it still didn't work. I changed the update() function so that it is like this:

Comment: I changed the code and it had the same problem. I changed it above so you can see the updated code: any other suggestions? Would you like all of the code?